# createDbInstance using AWS Aurora in javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, instance, amazon-aurora

I have a prototype app(Javascript app) in which I am trying to create a DB instance in AWS Aurora. The purpose of creating it through the app using the javascript API is so that we can delete the instance or save a snapshot when we are not using it.

I have tried using createDBCluster API call.

And created the cluster successfully. But I cannot use it as an endpoint from the mysql workbench without a DB instance in it.

`CreateDBInstance` did not work successfully. Can anyone provide a working code to `CreateDbInstance` from javascript?

I tried many combination of parameters until I reached a point where I could not understand the error.

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  please. 
Please add your code , what have you tried and ask where are you stuck. SoF community cant write complete code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Javascript SDK. But [this place](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html#createDBInstance-property) might be the best one to start.
Specifically look at following section in above link.

**Amazon Aurora**

*The name of the database to create when the primary instance of the DB cluster is created. If this parameter is not specified, no database is created in the DB instance.*